# Get Facebook Photo without user access token in Facebook application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

In my Facebook application, I use the following to retrieve photo from a public Facebook Page. The application is also added to this page as a Tab application.

```
FB.api({
        method : 'fql.query',
        query : 'SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id = '*photoId*'
    }
```

This was working fine but I noted that it will not work when the user has not given the permission to the application.

I get the following error.

```
Required valid saignature
```

Is there any other way where I can retrieve a photo by photo_id in Facebook without user having given the permission to the application.

I noted that using following too gives the same error

```
FB.api({
                    method : 'fql.query',
                    query : 'SELECT src FROM photo_src WHERE photo_id ='photoId' 
                }, function(data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api({                    
   method :'fql.query',                   
   query :'SELECT src FROM photo_src WHERE photo_id ='photoId'                 
}, function(data) {
```

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of just giving it.